# React DatePicker range with one input Style

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I'm new with react, and I need to use a DatePicker range, but it need to be with one input, where it shows two calendars, is that posible??
I can't find one with a style similar of this
Something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAzGB.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different Date range pickers libraries out there. I have use this one a couple of times and it's quite good, https://www.daterangepicker.com/ check the site for instructions.

To use you have to add the scripts on your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

And then create the input element somewhere on your component and initialize it

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
/*global $*/
/*To disable any eslint '$ not defined' errors*/

$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
    {
      opens: "left"
    },
    function(start, end, label) {
      console.log(
        "A new date selection was made: " +
          start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") +
          " to " +
          end.format("YYYY-MM-DD")
      );
    }
  );
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" name="daterange" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I added a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-rosalind-suegu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you, I believe that this datepicker will work  for what I want to do, thank you very much!